# disableIntervalMomentum is not working for IOS device in Flatlist (React Native)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I am using disableIntervalMomentum={true} to stop slider on next index. It is working for android but for IOS, on fast scrolling, it does not stop on next index but keeps moving.

here is my code

```
<FlatList
          ref={flatListRef}
          data={data?.offers || []}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          horizontal={true}
          bounces={(data?.offers || []).length > 1}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          snapToInterval={!isMultiCard ? snapToInterval : undefined}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
          viewabilityConfig={viewConfigRef.current}
          disableIntervalMomentum={true}
decelerationRate={'fast'}
            snapToOffsets={isMultiCard && length > 1 ? snapToOffsets : undefined}
            scrollEnabled={true}
/>
```

I added disableIntervalMomentum={true} but it is not working for IOS.
Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured that snapToOffsets was creating problem(because it was overriding pagingEnabled) so i removed it and it worked.